# Rails global variables are not updating on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `$template` variable defined in `application_controller.rb` which contains some site template code changed though admin

The problem is when I save or update it, it doesn't affect site till server restart, which is really uncomfortable in production

```
$template = Template.first
.....

$template.header.html_safe
```

In logs I can the that $template variable make and SQL and the very beginning (before Puma booted) and probably that's the way how global vars should be working.

P.S. Im using active_admin and update from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you fetch your `Template` and it is in memory, so after each `save` (:create, :update, create!, :update!, :save, :save!) you have to reload your variable

```
$template.reload
```

this will update your variable

or you can just add helper method to your `ApplicationController`

```
def first_template
  Template.first
end
helper_method :first_template
```

this will retrieve updated data each time

and you can use it in your view

```
first_template.header.html_safe
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. That's exactly what I was looking for. Спасибо :)